# D3.js Highlighting links on node selection

Tags: d3.js, hyperlink, highlight

so first, I have data in the format the same as miserables.json below
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

I would like to be able to make the link connected to my node red when I click the node.
So the psuedo⁻code would be like

```
selectAll(.links)
if links.source=nodeID or links.target=nodeID
then links.color=red
```

But I have not be able to do it. My ultimate goal would be intergrate it with Arc diagram below
http://bl.ocks.org/sjengle/5431779

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your pseudocode is a good start. You can use `filter` to implement the if condition in a selection. Note that the `.source` and `.target` of links are edited by d3, they are no longer the id of the nodes, but the node themselves:

```
thisNode = nodeObject; // where nodeObject is the javascript object for the node, it's probably called "d" in your function.
d3.selectAll(".link")
  .filter(function(d) {
     return (d.source === thisNode) || (d.target === thisNode);
   })
  .style("stroke", "red")
```

Comment: Thank you and Mehdi El Fadil so much. As an additional information for beginner like me, you have to set attr(class) for link when append() to use SelectAll(). I wasted so much time on that

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on top of @laurent's answer, to "reset" color of links that potentially were painted red during a previous interaction:

```
thisNode = nodeObject; // where nodeObject is the javascript object for the node, it's probably called "d" in your function.
d3.selectAll(".link")
  .style("stroke",function(d) {
     return d.source === thisNode || d.target === thisNode ? "red" : "#888888";
   })
```